# A tricky identity, involving block matrices, matrixexponential, the adjugate

Tags: linear-algebra

Hej everybody,

I have a somewhat specific problem, but I hope someone can help me or give me some advice. Here we go...

I have a complex valued $4\times 4$ matrix
$$\Delta=\begin{pmatrix}0 & a & 0 & 0 \\b & 0 & \mp c & \pm d\\d & 0 & e & g \\c & 0 & f & e\end{pmatrix}\;,$$
from which I calculate (with $\text{i}=\sqrt{-1}$)
$$T=\text{Exp}(\text{i}\Delta)\;.$$

I would like to show the following identity
$$adj(T_{12})T_{11}\mp adj(T_{22})T_{21}=0\;,$$
where the $2 \times 2$ block matrices $T_{ij}$ are defined by $T=\begin{pmatrix} T_{11} & T_{12} \\ T_{21} & T_{22}\end{pmatrix}$ and $adj(T_{ij})$ is the adjugate or classical adjoint of $T_{ij}$.

Does anybody have a suggestion how to tackle this?

Thanks a lot

Philipp

Comment: I would like to point out a couple things.

First I think the fact that $\Delta_{12} = \pm adj(\Delta_{21})$ must be key in showing this identity. In fact filling the zero-entries in $\Delta_{12}$ and $\Delta_{21}$ accordingly indicated no deviation from the identity during numerical calculations. It also would also match my expectations from a physics point of view.

Comment: Second, maybe the following helps. The exponential can be expanded into a finite series
$T=\text{Exp}(\text{i}\Delta)=\sum_{j=1}^4\text{Exp}(\text{i}q_j)\frac{(q_k\mathbf{E}-\Delta)(q_l\mathbf{E}-\Delta)(q_m\mathbf{E}-\Delta)}{(q_k-q_j)(q_l-q_j)(q_m-q_j)}\;,$
where $\mathbf{E}$ is the $4\times 4$ unit matrix, $q_n$ are the eigenvalues of $\Delta$ and $\{k,l,m\}=\{1,2,3,4\}\setminus j$.

Comment: Last, I want to mention that this identity is not a random guess. I have been working for years with a numerical method, in which I observed implications from this identity over and over again. I also did somewhat rigorous numerical testing of this identity. Therefore I am convinced that the identity is correct - I just can't figure out a way to prove it.

Comment: Can anybody help me with this?